# Combo SelectOption - Variável 0

Tags: php

Tenho uma página em HTML com algumas tabelas. dentre estas tabelas contém um ComboSelect e na ultima tabela um input text para preenchimento de uma data. Quando seleciono o comboselect e inputo a data e submito a página, os dados do comboselect não são salvados corretamente no banco, apenas acrescentando o "0". No apache o erro indica que a variável do combo select não foi definida/alimentada:

```
Undefined index: selectteste
```

**Formulário**

```
           <td>
             </a>
               &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a class="btn btn-danger" href="xxx.php?id=<?php echo $fetch['id']?>" aria-label="Settings">

              </a>

         </td>
   <form action="xxx.php?id=<?php echo $fetch['id']?>" method=post>
   <td><select name="selectteste" class="form-control"><meta charset="UTF-8">
   <option value="Teste">Teste Form</option>

</select>





<!-- Text input-->
<!--<form action="xxx.php?id=<?php echo $fetch['id']?>" method=post>-->

<td>

  <input  name="protocolo" type="text" placeholder="00/00/0000" style="width:100px;font-size: 13px" class="form-control protocolo input-md">
 <br>

  <input id="btn" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="OK" />

  </td>
</div>
```

**Pagina.php** **- Post**

```
$selectcombo = $_POST['selectteste'];
```

A única diferença que estas tabelas estão dentro de um While, pois existem outras informações a serem mostradas. Já joguei o inicio do `<form>` no topo da pagina e nada, porem não tenho mais ideia em como resolver.

Comment: Erro meu, a tabela que iria receber estes dados estava como inteiro, e por isso não era alimentado. Removi a coluna e inseri novamente como varchar e funcionou.